# how i can get views count on every searched videos using YouTube API v3 only

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, youtube-data-api

i am working on youtube api and searching videos by keyword, everything is working fine. but i need to add views count on every singe videos. how i can do that by hitting single api. because for getting views count i have hit another api with particular videoid , here is my code.

```
def search_video(request):

    response = {"status": False, "errors": []}

    query = request.POST.get('q', '')

    result = 5

    data = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=%s&part=snippet&key=%s&maxResults=%s" % (query, settings.DEVELOPER_KEY, result))

    if data.ok:
        response["result"] = data.json()
        response["status"] = True

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response))
```

Comment: The snippet part of the Google API doesn't deliver the view count. In order to access it, you have to access the statistics part of the Google API for a specific video ID. (e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY})

Comment: i know that but how i can map the views count for every single video. by using loop

Comment: Use `json` (Python library https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to iterate through the video ids, then for each element get the corresponding statistics-json from the google api.